# jQuery: Get class name from multiclass element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've selected the following element. What's the best way to get the class name icon_23123?

```
<div class="icon icon_23123"></div>
```

Is there something like [class^="icon_"] to select attributes instead of elements? 
Or should I get all the class names, and loop through to find one that begins with icon_?

EDIT: I want to write a function that gets any class name starting with icon_, and only those class names. Ultimately, I want to get the portion after the underscore, but it's not necessarily numeric- my plan was to use a regex (these class names are regular.)

EDIT2: The element I'm trying to get the class name from is already selected, I just need the class name from it (not every element in the document with a class="icon_.....")

EIDT3: My real problem was that I mixed data and styling. Since I don't care to support older browsers, I'm using data-id to hold the id of this datum.

```
<div class="icon icon_23123" data-id="23123"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use classes to store data, HTML5 provides a more convenient way to attach data to an element — [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*). For example:

```
<div class="icon" data-id="23123"></div>
```

Then you can read the attribute directly (the most cross-browser way):

```
var id = myelement.getAttribute('data-id');
```

or use the native [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property object:

```
var id = myelement.dataset.id;
```

or use the jQuery’s [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method for older browsers (IE10-):

```
var id = $(myelement).data('id');
```

It is also possible to use the same `data-` attribute to attach individual styles to the element via an attribute selector like `.icon[data-id="23123"]`.

Comment: I am using the class for styling, but your suggestion is helpful.

Comment: You can attach individual styles to element via attribute selector: `.icon[data-id="23123"]`, thus using `data-` attribute for both purposes.

Answer (score 1):

use .attr() combined with .each():

```
$('[class^="icon_"]').each(function () { console.log($(this).attr('class'); });
```

This passes all elements which have a class name that starts with `icon_` and pass it to the each function. You can then access the attribute of the element using .attr. If you only need to access the nth element, you could use `$('[class^=icon_]:eq(n)').attr('class')`

edit (answer to comment):

```
var classes = $(selectedElement).attr('class'),
    iconIndex = classes.indexOf('icon_'),
    iconIndex2 = classes.indexOf(' ', iconIndex),
    theClassName = classes.slice(iconIndex, (iconIndex2 > -1) ? iconIndex2 : undefined)
```

API documentation: [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: But there are 2 classes on the selected element. I only want the class name that begins with icon_.

Comment: late here (my brain hurts ^^) ;) better than looping through the classnames should be a combination of indexOf and slice - this should do the job :)