# .attr('class') is undefined on jQuery()

Tags: jquery, undefined

I've got a problem with my jquery function in a wordpress theme. I've used exactly this function severeal times and it worked. The function returns the ID of an Image, that was uploaded via the wordpress uploader.

Here is the relevant part:

```
// extract the img-ID from class attribute
var jt = jQuery('img', html).attr('class');
alert(html);
alert(jt);
j1 = jt.split(' ');
```

Both alerts are only there to figure out, what happens. alert(html) returns this:

```
<img src="http://www.xyz.com/files/2012/03/stage.jpg" alt="" title="" width="1000" height="371" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-6" />
```

but alert(jt) returns "undefined".

Any Idea? It would be great, if you could help.

Jan

Comment: code doesn't make sense...show how html gets defined and explain what you are trying to do with html as context argument

Comment: what you get on alert(html) ? is it a jqery object?

Comment: via .html() you ask for content between tags. is not for tag atributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of the context argument with your html variable is incorrect.  Per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), that context argument should be a DOM element, a document or a jQuery object.  It cannot be a string of HTML.

If, what you have is a string and you want to make it into a DOM object, you can do that a number of ways.

This code will create a DOM object from the html string you have and then retrieve the class attribute from that DOM object.

```
var html = '<img src="http://www.xyz.com/files/2012/03/stage.jpg" alt="" title="" width="1000" height="371" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-6" />';
var item = jQuery(html);
var jt = item.attr('class');
alert(jt);
j1 = jt.split(' ');
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/phnED/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
jQuery('img', html)
```

The context is `html` and apparently `html` is an image so you're looking for a `img` inside an `img` which it won't find.

**EDIT:**
If `html` is `<img src="http://www.xyz.com/files/2012/03/stage.jpg" alt="" title="" width="1000" height="371" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-6" />` then you can grab the class like this:

```
var klass = $(html).attr('class');

// You could do this to create an array of all classes
var klasses = $(html).attr('class').match(/\S+/g);
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions, what I can use instead of jQuery('img', html) ?

Comment: I think others have the right answer too but I just edited my answer. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

The context variable `html` you provided is undefined at that time, and you should define it as the DOM element that the image is a child of.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// extract the img-ID from class attribute
var html = jQuery('.some-class');
var jt = jQuery('img', html).attr('class');
alert(html);
alert(jt);
j1 = jt.split(' ');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

http://jsfiddle.net/ssUhJ/

Answer (score 0):

`attr('class')` does work. Probably your context var (`html`) is just undefined.

By the way, to store data, it makes sense to use [HTML5 custom data- attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551116/1211187) instead of classes.

Comment: html is defined. You can see the content of html in my original question. I know that this code is not the best solution. But I want to use wordpress own image uploader and this image-tag in my Question is the only thing it returns.
I have no influence on what it returns, because I'm writing a theme and editing the core files is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

When having the given html-string, this should normally work:

```
 $(html).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

without html

```
var jt = jQuery('img').attr('class');
alert(jt);
j1 = jt.split(' ');
alert(j1);
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to the OP if you explained the code that you're using. Just writing a piece of code without explanation doesn't really work well in a QA format.

Comment: The answer (explain) was posted as comment right to the post question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `var jt = jQuery('img', html)`, from [jquery document](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), the second parameter is the context of the jquery object. check the modified program on http://jsfiddle.net/hYKnd/.

Answer (score -1):

As of jquery 1.6 (see [docs for .attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)), the `.attr` switched from returning an empty string to returning `undefined`.

Open this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QVqXC/ and change the jquery version loaded and see how the output message changes.